# how to get total number of pixels in each bin of a histogram in opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv

how to get total number of pixels in each bin of a histogram in opencv?
I have 256 bins.I need to get total number of pixels fall in each bin. 
I tried with following code.But it is not working properly.

```
for( i = 0; i < 256 ; i++)
{
std::cerr << "value " << i << "=" << hist.at<float>(i) << endl;
}
```

Comment: Why exactly do you assume this code doesn't work properly?

Comment: could you provide us more code to see what is in hist? Also it would help you to get an answer quickly if you can explain what do you exactly mean by "working properly" ... the code is not executing or it is printing wrong values etc.